# Controls are vanishing after adding reference to angular library

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. If I add the reference to angular lib on top of the page then I am getting empty page back. Don't know what is the reason. 
Here is a code

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js" type ="text/javascript" />
 <body>
 <div ng-app>
 <input type="text" id="txt1" ng-model = "data"/><br />
 The value is {{ data }}

 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close your script tag properly to load script from `cdn`, `script` tag are not self closing to close it like `/>` at the tag end. So instead `/>` use `</script>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js" 
  type ="text/javascript">
</script>
```